# Produce a report between two tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Thank for contributing in my learning. 
I am a new learner in SQL 
the homework is asking to find how many times each book title has been borrowed. they are found in different tables (Book(ISBAN,title,edition, year) and BookLoan(copyNo, dataOut, dateDue,borrowerNo))and moreover they dont have a foreign key. I am confused.. I dont know how to join these two tables?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to have a key to join tables, but from the available columns I can only assume that the ISBAN and copyNo are the same thing, since you can't make any useful joins on title, edition or year.

If this is the case, something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
Book.Title,
COUNT(BookLoan.copyNo)
FROM 
Book INNER JOIN BookLoan ON Book.ISBAN=BookLoan.copyNo
GROUP BY
Book.Title
ORDER BY 
COUNT(BookLoan.copyNo) DESC
```